# specific elements from a LinkedList from one class to another

Tags: java, linked-list

I have this current class that contains all these ingredients which I am trying to add into another linked list but I am struggling.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Kitchen {
    public static final Category CRUST = new Category("crust", 1, 1);
    public static final Category SAUCE = new Category("sauce", 1, 1);
    public static final Category TOPPING = new Category("topping", 2, 3);
    private Category[] categories = { CRUST, SAUCE, TOPPING };
    private LinkedList<Ingredient> ingredients = new LinkedList<Ingredient>();

    public Kitchen() {
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Thin", 3.00, CRUST));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Thick", 3.50, CRUST));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Tomato", 1.00, SAUCE));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Barbeque", 1.00, SAUCE));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Capsicum", 0.50, TOPPING));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Olives", 1.50, TOPPING));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Jalapenos", 1.00, TOPPING));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Beef", 2.75, TOPPING));
        ingredients.add (new Ingredient("Pepperoni", 2.50, TOPPING));
    }
```

this is the class that contains all of the ingredients and this is the class which I am trying to copy some of the ingredients to.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Pizza {
    private LinkedList<Ingredient> ingredients = new LinkedList<Ingredient>();
    private int sold;

    public void add(){  
        ...
        ...
            if (...);
                ingredients.add(...);
        ...
    }
```

How should I go about adding SPECIFIC ingredients from Kitchen into ingredients in Pizza (not just clone the whole thing :))? I've tried just adding the ingredient itself but that does not seem to work. (inredients.add(ingredient))

Answer (score 0):

You can use enum instead of LinkedList to store all of the ingredients. Add a enum for ingredient in class Kitchen.

```
public enum Ingredient {
    THIN("Thin", 3.00, CRUST),
    THICK("Thick", 3.50, CRUST);
    // add other ingredient
    private String name;
    private double cost;
    private Category category;

    private Ingredient(String name, double cost, Category category) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Then in class Pizza.

```
public void add() { 
    ingredients.add(Ingredient.THICK);
    // add other ingredient needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `getIngredients()` method to the `Kitchen` class which returns the provided ingredients by the Kitchen. This allows you to access the ingredients of the `Kitchen` out of the `Pizza` class (and further classes).